# ui-router child views not running controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Trying to get the following url structure to work:

```
/page/
/page/article
/page/article/third-level-1
/page/article/third-level-2
```

Ive tried the follow but it doesn't render the article view at all. The page view renders fine:

```
<section ui-view></section>

$stateProvider
  .state('index', {
    external: true,
    url: '/'
  })
  .state('page', {
    url: '/page',
    controller: Controller,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    templateUrl: '/static/views/page/page.html',
  })
  .state('page.article', {
    url: '/article/',
    controller: Controller,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    templateUrl: '/static/views/page/page-article.html'
  });
```

I then tried everything under the sun, and managed to get the second view to render with the following, however the Controller doesnt run on the article view:

```
<section ui-view="app"></section>

$stateProvider
  .state('index', {
    external: true,
    url: '/'
  })
  .state('page', {
    url: '/page',
    views: {
      'app': {
        controller: Controller,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        templateUrl: '/static/views/page/page.html',
      }
    }
  })
  .state('page.article', {
    url: '/article/',
    views: {
      'app@': {
        controller: Controller,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        templateUrl: '/static/views/page/page-article.html',
      }
    }
  });
```

How can i get the child view to render and use the/a controller? Haven't even gotten down to the third level.

Answer (score 0):

It should be this.

```
.state('page.article', {
url: '/page/article/',
views: {
  'app@': {
    controller: Controller,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    templateUrl: '/static/views/page/page-article.html',
  }
}
```